# How can virtualenv be used effectively with libraries stored in source control?

Tags: python, version-control, dependencies, virtualenv

I am aware of 2 suggested practices which seem to be at odds with each other:

1. Store everything you need for your project in source control. When working with C++ apps we'd check all our libs into source control so that a new developer always has everything he or she needs to build and run the project, even if the 3rd party libraries are no longer available online.
2. Use `virtualenv` with Python projects to isolate a project and its dependencies from upgrades done to the system Python. Each library installed lives inside the virtualenv, and usually virtualenvs are tied to a specific path (as suggested in the documentation) and it's expected that developers install the environment themselves, and then presumably add any libaries that are dependencies.

Ideally I'd like to be able to install new dependencies into a virtualenv inside my source control repository, check it in, and then other developers will get the correct dependencies when they update, with no conflicts no matter what libraries their system Python has installed. But I appreciate that there is going to be an issue with checking a whole virtualenv into source control as different developers might run different interpreters (based on their OS) and might need different builds of certain extensions. Perhaps this limits how far I can go with this approach.

So, is there a compromise that minimises the amount of manual installation of libraries that needs to be done on each machine, and which keeps as much as possible in source control to reduce the risk of packages disappearing from the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check a pip bundle into source control: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#bundles

You can use --index-url to tell pip where to get the packages if you want to store them on your network so they don't have to get them from PyPI or wherever: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#alternate-package-repositories

Each developer would have their own virtualenv and they would keep it updated.  You can have an update script in source control that they run periodically.

Comment: That solves the availability problem, but installing the packages is still done manually, correct?

Comment: There is no other way.  Everyone would have to install and update their own virtualenv.  I think a source control hook as you mentioned in the other comment would have to do.

Comment: Ok, second question: how do these pip bundles work for 3rd party libraries? Would they work with eggs? The docs there aren't exactly bursting with detail on how the command works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by using a combination of virtualenv and pip. With pip you can freeze requirements using:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

On another virtualenv environment you can install the requirements with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

More reading: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#freezing-requirements

Comment: How would someone performing an update know that they need to run the second instruction? Would that have to be done with a source control hook?

Comment: Yeah, that could work. Or supply a README file that suggests it. As far as I know it's a fairly common practice.